# Testing whether a method in my controller was called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test whether a method in my controller has been called or not.

My Controller looks like this:

```
def index
  if id_filters
    @products = Product.where(id: id_filters)
  else
    @products = Product.paginate(params[:page].to_i, params[:per].to_i)
  end

render json: @products, meta: @products.meta
end
```

I saw people using the code below to do this so I attempted to test it in RSpec with:

```
controller.stub!(:paginate).and_return true
```

however, I get an error:

```
undefined method `stub!' for #<ProductsController:0x00000102bd4d38>
```

I also tried:

```
controller.stub(:paginate).and_return true
```

same result though, it is an undefined method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CORRECT SYNTAX**

If you are using rspec **before version 3.0** the correct syntax is

```
controller.should receive(:paginate).and_return(true)
# OR this equivalence
controller.should receive(:paginate) { true }
# OR (when you are in "controller" specs)
should receive(:paginate) { true }
```

If you are using rspec **version 3.0 or higher** the correct syntax is

```
expect(controller).to receive(:paginate) { true }
# OR (when you are in "controller" specs)
is_expected.to receive(:paginate) { true }
```

**YOUR CODE**

You seem to be testing `paginate` for `Product` so you syntax should be:

```
# Rspec < 3.0
Product.should receive(:paginate) { true }
# Rspec >= 3.0
expect(Product).to receive(:paginate) { true }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Using Rails 3.0 so expect(Product).to receive(:paginate) { true } worked beautifully. Now this spawns a new question (in case you haven't realized I am VERY new to RSpec).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to be stubbing Product, not the controller.